# String with different operators in JavaScript match

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have the following JS var:

```
var tokens = str.match(/\[|\]|< number|\)|and |(?:(?!and )[^\[\]])+/g);
```

`tokens` is later used in a `switch()` statement.

This matches occurrences of:

- `[`
- `]`
- `< number`
- `)`
- `and` (with a space at the end)

However, I would like to precede `number` not only by `<` but possibly also by other operators. The following are needed:

- `>`
- `>=`
- `<`
- `<=`

So `match` also has to look for `< number`, `<= number`, `> number`, `>= number`. Is there a quick and easy way to do this by, for instance, defining a wildcard/variable for the possible operators?

Comment: Try replacing `<` with `=?[<>]=?` (note: this *will* match `=<=` and `=>=`).

Comment: @Sam Hm, good call but I'd rather keep it clean and leave `=>=` and `=>=` out of it.

Comment: `tokens` will be an array. Since two arrays are equal only if the reference in memory is the same, I'm not sure how they can be used in a `switch` statement.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to solve that problem, but starting with `[<>]` will match either greater or less than.

Comment: @Oriol They'll be used in a `for` loop with `var token = tokens[i]`.

Comment: Your regex already matches `<= number`... and many other strings. The part after the last | doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the expression `[<>]=? number`.

`[<>]` means either `<` or `>`.

`=?` is an optional `=` sign.